# Odd performance of PostGIS Select Query with ST_AsText?

Tags: postgis, select

I have this query:

```
    select ST_AsText(geo) as wkt, city, street_number, street_name, street_type,
           street_direction, street_unit 
           from parcels_union 
           order by id 
           LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 18000
```

I takes 5500ms to run.

This query without the ST_Astext runs in 22ms. So I would expect it is taking some time to AsText my geometries.

Now here is the weird part. This query also runs in 5500ms even though it is returning 5 times as many rows:

```
    select ST_AsText(geo) as wkt, city, street_number, street_name, street_type,
           street_direction, street_unit 
           from parcels_union 
           order by id 
           LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 18000
```

This tells me there is a fixed overhead to using AsText which I do not find particularly odd in itself, but 5.5 seconds?

Any ideas on how to bypass this overhead or otherwise optimize this?

Comment: How about LIMIT 1 OFFSET 18000?

Comment: Same timing - though timing keeps changing. Now everything takes 30,000ms. I am on the trail of a suspect. Will report back what I find.

Comment: Is there a lot of use on the database you're connecting to?

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out the problem was a couple of humongous geometries in my table. One was 2GB and the other was 1 GB. This was a result of an ST_UNION I did and was not expecting that result!

Killed those two records and the queries run much faster and the time to return results is more linear with larger limits.

The large geometries were causing me all sorts of difficulties like using up 166GB+ of hard drive space (causing me to run out!) while doing an update query. My query was trying to update many of my rows with those huge geometries.

Two mysteries solved at once.

Comment: You should accept your own answer.